# Can you activate multiple Segues at once?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Say in story board I have View Controller A, View Controller B, C, D, E, F

View controller A is connected to B by "Show Segue"

View controller B is connected to C by "Show Segue"

Then C is connected to D then D to E then E to F

When a user clicks a button on View Controller A, I want to trigger Segue A to B then B to C then C to D then D to E then E to F in order to organically "stack" the view controllers in the hierarchy of view controller stacks.

How can I achieve such with just the user clicking a button.

Comment: You can perform b->c segue in b's viewdidappear method, perform c->d segue in c's viewdidappear method. But the transition animation will be visible to the user. Its better to use a navigation controller and perform push programmatically.

Comment: What do you mean by _organically "stack"_ ?

Comment: I want "back" button on top left to be able to move backwards views F to E to D to C to B to A if the user tries to back themselves from the navigation @ShubhamBakshi

Comment: @BlueBug If you want _Back Button_ out-of-the-box, then you need to go with Navigation Controller ! Otherwise you'll have to create your own button on each ViewController and then call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` in each ViewController's Back Button action

Answer (score 0):

ViewController A

- do segue to ViewController B in button click event.

ViewController B

- do segue to ViewController C in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad` method.

as same for remaining controller (not in ViewController F as its last).

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` of **View Controller A**, use `performSegueWithIdentifier` for A -> B.

In `viewDidLoad` of **View Controller B**, use `performSegueWithIdentifier` for B -> C.

In `viewDidLoad` of **View Controller C**, use `performSegueWithIdentifier` for C -> D.

In `viewDidLoad` of **View Controller D**, use `performSegueWithIdentifier` for D -> E.

In `viewDidLoad` of **View Controller E**, use `performSegueWithIdentifier` for E -> F.

Another solution would be to stop using segues and to instantiate View Controllers **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, **E** from the storyboard with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and set the `viewControllers` property of your navigation controller as an array: [instance of **A**, instance of **B**, instance of **C**, instance of **D**, instance of **E**, instance of **F**]